# How to cache a list of custom-defined models in Django?

Tags: python, django, pickle

I have a list of models, [Book1, Book2, Book3], that I need to cache. I get this error, when I try to cache them: can't pickle _Element objects
Here is the code that I am using:

```
if cache.get(isbn):
    sellers = cache.get(isbn)
else:
    sellers = get_all_amazon_sellers(isbn)
    cache.set(isbn, sellers, 600)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: What does your model look like?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to convert your data into a python [list](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html), as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615721/setting-an-object-in-the-django-cache-api-fails-due-to-pickle-error)

Comment: Hi, the variable "sellers" is a python list. The function "get_all_amazon_sellers" returns a list of sellers, like so: [SellerObj1, SellerObj2, SellerObj3... SellerObjN].

Answer (score 0):

May be some value in your list is special type, and not common python object. I met the same trouble when I want to pickle texts which are parsed with lxml.Some useful links:[lxml question](https://answers.launchpad.net/lxml/+question/97887) and [my record](http://stonelee.iteye.com/admin/blogs/983644).